# Unable to plot pcolormesh on Basemap

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib-basemap

In my program , there is a function for plotting 
pcolormesh on  Basemap. This function is called in a loop, if I am calling this function once then I am able to plot pcolormesh on  Basemap but if I am calling this function multiple times then only the first loop it is able to plot pcolormesh on  Basemap and  the reaming iterations. It is plotting only basemap with empty pcolormesh.Below is the code.

```
cbar_opt = "vertical"

fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_subplot(111)



if(ptype == 1): # Contour plot
    plot = axes.contourf(xs,ys,field,levels=clevels,cmap=cmap)
elif(ptype == 2): # pcolor plot
    # Mask values below lower bounds
    field = N.ma.masked_where(field < clevels[0],field)
    try:
        cmapname = cmap.name[-9:]
    except:
        cmapname = None
    if cmapname == "_discrete":
        norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=clevels[0], vmax=clevels[-1])
    else:
        norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(clevels,cmap.N)

    plot = axes.pcolormesh(x,y,field,vmin=clevels[0],vmax=clevels[-1],cmap=cmap,norm=norm,edgecolors='None',antialiased=False,rasterized=True)instead

if len(clevels) > 20:
    cintvs = tickLocations(clevels, cbar_opt, maxsize=20)
    clvllocator = MultipleLocator(base=cintvs[1] - cintvs[0])
else:
    cintvs = clevels
    clvllocator = FixedLocator(cintvs)

divider = make_axes_locatable(axes)
if(cbar_opt == "vertical"):
     cax = divider.append_axes("right",size="5%",pad=0.05)
     plt.colorbar(plot,orientation='vertical',ticks=clvllocator,cax=cax)
else:
     cax = divider.append_axes("top",size="5%",pad=0.05)
     cax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
     plt.colorbar(plot,orientation='horizontal',ticks=clvllocator,cax=cax)
if(ovrfieldopt):
     plotovr = axes.contour(xs,ys,ovrfield,levels=ovrfieldlvl,colors='k',lw=2,alpha=0.25)
if(gis_info != None and bgmap != None):
    gis_x, gis_y = bgmap(*gis_info[1:][::-1])
    axes.plot(gis_x, gis_y,'ko')

formatter = FuncFormatter(mtokm)
axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
axes.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(base=xtickintv)) # Configurable in input file 
axes.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(base=ytickintv)) # Configurable in input file (TAS 9-6-13)
axes.set_xlabel('km')
axes.set_ylabel('km')

if(xtickintv == ytickintv):     
    axes.set_aspect('equal')
if(ovrmap and bgmap != None): 
    bgmap.drawcoastlines(ax=axes)
    bgmap.drawcountries(ax=axes)

# Set the axes limits after the basemap calls, because basemap resets the axes limits 
axes.set_xlim(xlim[0],xlim[1])
axes.set_ylim(ylim[0],ylim[1])


return fig, axes
```

Comment: Thanks dilberted for the changes

Comment: You should give some code that reproduce your error.